# mount cifs: access not allowed for few files

Tags: linux, filesystems, cifs

I have a QNAP nas with smb shares.

A share is mounted on my debian with following command:

```
 sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.28/Photos /tmp/tmpxsenalsl/ -o credentials=/home/seb/.nascredentials,vers=2.0
```

For most of the files I have no issues to access. But there are few files that cannot be read: `sudo cp`, `sudo hexdump`, `sudo md5sum` .. all fail due to "not allowed" error.

But I don't see anything special in these files.
For example, `ls` gives :

```
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 606716 févr. 29 16:26 43400122.jpg
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 546823 févr. 29 16:26 43400116.jpg
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 714331 févr. 29 16:26 43400054.jpg
```

The following command is allowed

```
sudo cp 43400116.jpg /tmp
```

The following command is not allowed

```
sudo cp 43400054.jpg /tmp
```

When I use Windows to browse this share, I am allowed to access to 43400054.jpg

How is it possible to investigate this issue?

Thanks
Sebastien

Comment: Have you tried mounting it in another directory such as `/mnt`?

Comment: What if you _don't_ use `sudo`?

Comment: Do you have basic (default) share-based authentication on the QNAP or have you enabled full Windows ACLs?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you add `noperm` to the mount options?

Comment: Same issue when  I mount to /mnt/test or when I don't use sudo or when I use noperm

Comment: on the QNAP, the share allows the user to read/write

Comment: An update: I have no issue when I mount with the admin user, but I sill have the issue with I mount with the other user. On Windows, I tried with the admin user

Comment: It seems the QNAP-user you're using in your  `.nascredentials` doesn't have sufficient rights to read `43400054.jpg`. Pls. check owner and permissions on the QNAP itself.

Comment: The user has the same rights for all the files. See result of ls -l in the description above